# How to wait until JDialog is fully created

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I need to calculate window decorations somehow. So I override `JDialog`'s constructor. But when I call `get_decoration_size()` it sometimes returns wrong values. And my thought was: window creates later than `get_decoration_size()` executes(strange, because both in same thread and in same constructor). So I decided to sleep for a second, and it worked, and now decorations always valid.

My question is: is there a way to "join" to the creating process(wait until window is shown by `setVisible(true)`)? If so, it must be something to replace `unsafe_sleep(1000)`.

```
package swing.window;

import db.db;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import static swing.util.*;
import static util.util.unsafe_sleep;

public class calc_decor extends JDialog {
        {
                //some initializations
                setLayout(null);
                setResizable(false);
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Loading...");
                add(label);
                setxy(label, 3, 3);
                fit(label);
                setsize(this, label.getWidth() + 100, label.getHeight() + 100);
                window_to_center(this);

                setVisible(true);//trying to draw

                unsafe_sleep(1000);//without that it looks like get_decoratoin_size()
                                   //is called before setVisible(true)

                db.sysdecor = get_decoration_size();//trying to get decorations
                dispose();
        }

        private Dimension get_decoration_size() {
                Rectangle window = getBounds();
                Rectangle content = getContentPane().getBounds();
                int width = window.width - content.width;
                int height = window.height - content.height;
                return new Dimension(width, height);
        }
}
```

Comment: *"I need to calculate window decorations somehow."* ... ***Why?*** See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) **General tip:** For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I did not previously notice `setLayout(null);` .. Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to assume a lot to create a runnable example.

Here's the result of your getDecorationSize method.  The line didn't print until I closed the JDialog.

```
java.awt.Dimension[width=16,height=39]
```

And here's the code I used.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JDialogTest implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JDialogTest());
    }

    private JFrame frame;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("JDialog Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                150, 100, 150, 100));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

        JButton button = new JButton("Open JDialog");
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        panel.add(button);

        return panel;
    }

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new CalculateDecor(frame, "Spash Screen");
        }

    }

    public class CalculateDecor extends JDialog {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public CalculateDecor(JFrame frame, String title) {
            super(frame, true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setTitle(title);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Loading...");
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            panel.add(label);

            add(panel);
            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
            setVisible(true);

            System.out.println(getDecorationSize());
        }

        private Dimension getDecorationSize() {
            Rectangle window = getBounds();
            Rectangle content = getContentPane().getBounds();
            int width = window.width - content.width;
            int height = window.height - content.height;
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }

    }

}
```